# Time Weighted Samples when using Random Forest

Tags: random-forest

I am wondering if there is a best practice for exponentially weight the training samples for random forest by time (putting more weights on more recent samples)? One way I can think of is to sample the full dataset with replacements according to the weights given time. Are there any other methods I should consider? It would be great if anyone knows some python packages that could help me accomplish this goal. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, please try to ask questions about a specific problem, preferably with a bit of source code. As written in the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sklearn implementation of Random Forests allows to specify sample weights in the [fit function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.fit).

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
# fill sample_weight with the desired weighting
sample_weights = numpy.ones(y.shape)
estimator = RandomForestClassifier
estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weights)
```